# What is the name of this graph data structure from quake map compiler? And what are some alternatives for Rust?

Tags: c++, c, rust, data-structures, graph

I came across this data structure in the [source code for the quake map compiler](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-Tools/blob/master/qutils/QBSP/PORTALS.C) (specifically for portal graph generation), you can look at the specific implementation and its usage over there. Here's a quick summary:

`Node`s are connected by `Portal`s.
A node has a pointer to a linked list of `portals`:

```cpp
struct Node {
    Portal *portals,
    // ..
}
```

However, because a portal is connected to two `nodes`, it keeps track of two:

```cpp
struct Portal {
    Node *nodes[2],
    // ..
}
```

The nodes are ordered as the front node and the back node, depending on the orientation of the portal. (There is a deterministic way of determining which side of a portal is back and which is front, but for this summary it doesn't matter.)

Because a portal is used as a linked list, it also keeps track of two `nexts`, one for each node:

```cpp
struct Portal {
    // ..
    Portal *nexts[2],
}
```

To iterate over the list of portal in a given node:

```cpp
int side;
for (portal = node.portals; portal; portal->nexts[side]) {
    // to determine which next is our own
    side = portal->nodes[0] == node? 0: 1;
    // rest of the code
}
```

An example of a portal graph represented by this data structure:

```
    (Node_A) — Portal_1 — (Node_B) — Portal_5 — (Node_E)
        |                     |                              /
    Portal_2              Portal_3                    front / back
        |                     |                            /
    (Node_C) — Portal_4 — (Node_D)
```

A simple structure like above is represented like this: (for simplicity, portals are sorted by the number)

```
Node_A -> Portal_1
Node_B -> Portal_1
Node_C -> Portal_2
Node_D -> Portal_3
Node_E -> Portal_5

Portal_1 -> nexts: [Portal_2, Portal_3], nodes: [Node_A, Node_B]
Portal_2 -> nexts: [Null    , Portal_4], nodes: [Node_A, Node_C]
Portal_3 -> nexts: [Portal_5, Portal_4], nodes: [Node_B, Node_D]
Portal_4 -> nexts: [Null    , Null    ], nodes: [Node_C, Node_D]
Portal_5 -> nexts: [Null    , Null    ], nodes: [Node_B, Node_E]

// Alternatively, if I regroup them as front and back (which I think is easier to grasp):

Portal_1 -> front: [Portal_2, Node_A], back: [Portal_3, Node_B]
Portal_2 -> front: [Null    , Node_A], back: [Portal_4, Node_C]
Portal_3 -> front: [Portal_5, Node_B], back: [Portal_4, Node_D]
Portal_4 -> front: [Null    , Node_C], back: [Null    , Node_D]
Portal_5 -> front: [Null    , Node_B], back: [Null    , Node_E]

// read as: the front node is (nodes[front]), and the next that belongs to this node is (nexts[front]), etc.
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a name for this data structure?
2. If I were to implement something similar in Rust for a similar use case, how could I implement it or what are some viable alternatives? Seems like this specific data structure was chosen for the original project because it is easy to detach and put new portals in place, peek to the other side, etc. I would've just kept it if it weren't for the fact that linked lists aren't really suitable for Rust.

Comment: From your diagram it's unclear why `Portal_3 -> nexts` contains `Portal_5` but not `Portal_1` and similar why `Portal_1 -> nexts` contains `Portal_3` but not `Portal_5`

Comment: The pattern of having a `next` (or in this case two "nexts") inside Portal is an example of an Intrusive Linked List. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581889/intrusive-algorithms-equivalents-in-rust) asks about intrusive linked lists in rust.

Comment: @cafce25 it works like linked lists, it only contains the portal right next to itself in the order of the list. for convenience, I sorted the portals by the number. from the side of `Node_B`, the list is like so: `Portal_1 -> Portal_3 -> Portal_5 -> null`. `Portal_1` only references `Portal_3`, `Portal_3` only references `Portal_5` and so on.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, I didn't know the specific variant of a linked list was called that. Some people suggested using a vec or an arena and keeping the implementation but I'm not really sure if that's the best way to go about doing it or if i should use a different graph representation. I also wanted to know if using linked lists like this for a graph like this had a name

Comment: Formally the intrusive linked list starting from `node->portals` is an implementation of the adjacency list of the node. (where all neighbours are portals, and the neighbours of a portal are nodes again) How you implement that adjacency list in Rust strongly depends on what you want to do with it. If you don't need extra information about portals you can forego them and just have a `neighbours : Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>` . Otherwise you would have a similar vector for `portals`.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, in the code, the nodes are created during the binary space partitioning process (it is needed for portal generation), and portals hold polygon data. Actually, during the portal generation process, temporary portals are created, freed and replaced until leaf nodes are encountered, so a vec might not be the best solution.

Comment: Vecs are fine until proven otherwise ;) But for clarity it might be worthwhile to have a separate data structure while the BSP is under construction and then a conversion to a final datastructure.

Comment: Intrusive data structures are very common in C for various reasons. They're very *un*common in Rust, because it has generics and high-level datastructures, and because intrusive structures confuse ownership which the language really dislikes. You could use refcounts and inner mutability but it brings its own  issues. The more common alternative would probably be to go more ECS, store all the nodes in a vec/map and store the indices / identifiers of the siblings in the node.

Comment: This wouldn't work for a triangle of 3 nodes connected by 3 portals (2 portals per node) because one of the nodes would be on different numbered sides of its two portals.

Comment: @IanAbbott this is why we check which side the node we're on is every iteration